# How to retrieve multiple images saved as medium blob and then save the image into an arrayList?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I created a class called images and had a list imageHolder member variable to contain multiple images and then uploaded it to the database successfully, but my problems is how do I retrieve multiple images using the mvc pattern. I'm using MySQL dbms.

I understand I have to convert the blob type to part type to insert it into the list.

//the code below is how I inserted the images into the database

```
        InputStream inputStream;

        for (Part imgFile : img.getImageHolder()) {

            inputStream = imgFile.getInputStream();
            ps = connection.prepareStatement
           ("INSERT INTO images(username,image) VALUES (?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, img.getUsername());
            ps.setBlob(2, inputStream);
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

}
//the image retrieval method

```
         List<Part> imageHolder = new ArrayList<>();

         ps = connection.prepareStatement
         ("SELECT * FROM images WHERE username=?");
         ps.setString(1,adName);

         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

          while(rs.next()){

          Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");
          //conversion I'm stuck with
          imageHolder.add(imagefile);

          }
```

On conversion of blob to part I can insert the image to the arrayList and then return the images object to the servlet when its being called. And then I can access all the images that belong to the specific user. Well thats what I came up with. I'd appreciate any suggestions you have for my code or my idea for the image insertion and retrieval process that I'm using. Thank you in advance